# Possible XML tags/functions for use in swagger documentations?

Tags: c#, xml, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, xml-documentation

For example, I remember reading that you could make a table in XML by writing something similar to the following:

```
||__Column__||                              
||    row   ||
```

Sadly, I can't remember the source, or what it was called. Is there a place that has documented all these neat little things, if not, could someone shine some light on them?

I'm not entirely sure if the above was exclusive to swashbuckle, or general XML. Please edit this question if it's about XML in general. If you can't - let me know.

Comment: The DataSet method in c# has a WriteXm(file or stream)l method as well as a read method.  It only works on simple xml structures that have up to 4 layers of tags.

Comment: @jdweng I'm using the [following](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#including-xml-comments) for XML documentation in Swashbuckle.

Comment: Xml is shown on following page : https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/representing-xml/

Comment: Sadly that's not how you actually apply it via swashbuckle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic XML documentation looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieves a specific product by unique id
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Awesomeness!</remarks>
/// <response code="200">Product created</response>
/// <response code="400">Product has missing/invalid values</response>
/// <response code="500">Oops! Can't create your product right now</response>
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Product), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IDictionary<string, string>), 400)]
[ProducesResponseType(500)]
public Product GetById(int id)
```

Worth pointing out you do have to enable that:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#include-descriptions-from-xml-comments

The table you show looks like markup maybe what you trying to do is add that in the documentation...
You can include more in the `<remarks>`, HTML and Markup is valid syntax

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Testing the summary on the ApiExplorerController
    /// </summary>
    ///
    /// <remarks>
    /// Testing the description on the ApiExplorerController
    /// This is a second line
    /// Here is a link to <a href="https://github.com/heldersepu">my GitHub profile</a>
    /// <br/>
    /// Some HTML styling: <b>BOLD</b> <i>italics</i>
    /// <ul>
    /// <li>Item one</li>
    /// <li>Item two</li>
    /// </ul>
    /// <pre>Text in a pre element</pre>
    ///
    /// <h1>Header1</h1>
    /// <h2>Header2</h2>
    /// <h3>Header3</h3>
    /// </remarks>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
```

Here is how that looks like in the UI:
http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=ApiExplorer#/ApiExplorer/ApiExplorer_Get

---

Here is a markup table

```
    ///<summary>Post</summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Testing Markdown table
    /// | a | b | c | d | e |
    /// |---|---|---|---|---|
    /// | 3 | 0 | 7 | 4 | 1 |
    /// | 4 | 1 | 8 | 5 | 2 |
    /// | 5 | 2 | 9 | 6 | 3 |
    /// </remarks>
    [Route("Post Arrays")]
    public Arrays Post(Arrays arrays)
```

The table is a bit stretched out on the UI:
http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=ArrayTest#/ArrayTest/ArrayTest_Post

Comment: Thank you Helder! What I'm showing is what you literally can write in the XML comment section, which will be rendered as a full blown table (not just an ordered list)
I'm not sure of the exact syntax, I read it somewhere here on stackoverflow. I'd just like to know where it comes from, and if there's anything else out there like it. I don't think it's HTML. If you could shine some light on that, It'd be the icing on the cake!

Comment: What is this `XML comment section` you talking about? and that table looks like maybe Markup

Comment: This is exactly what I saw! Markdown table. Is it part of HTML? Are there any other fancy things offered for XML in swashbuckle? Thank you so much!

Comment: @SpiritBob Markdown and HTML are two different languages ... `other fancy things` not sure what you mean, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Oh, nothing specific! I just never knew I could use such syntax. I'm guessing I just need to lookup what Markdown in general has to offer? As it seems it can be applied to XML documentation? Is it for XML documentation in general, or only for swashbuckle?